# Lucene fulltext search autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, lucene, full-text-search

I'm trying to implemetn autocomplete feature with Lucene.

For example I have the following values:

```
javascript-object
javascript-array
javascript-library
javascript
```

Right now, I configured Lucene index with `whitespace` analyzer.

When I use the following query: `javascript*` I expect `javascript` term to be on the first place. But in the result set - the `javascript` is not on the first place.

Please advise how to properly configure Lucene in order to get `javascript` on the first place when I use for example the following queries:

```
java*
javas*
javascript*
```